# Check for internet access always returns true

Tags: delphi, internet-connection

The following code always returns True on my system:

```
uses
    WinInet;

function CheckInternetConnection() : Boolean;
var
    dwConnectionTypes: Integer;
begin
    dwConnectionTypes := (
        INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM +
        INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN +
        INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY);     // "dwConnectionTypes" now "7"
    if (InternetGetConnectedState(@dwConnectionTypes, 0)) then
        Result := True      // Always hit, "dwConnectionTypes" now "18"
    else
        Result := False;    // Never reaches here!
end;
```

I've tried:

```
* unplugging the network cable
* stopped "Wireless Zero Configuration" service
* disabled all connections in Control Panel > Network Connections
* definitely confirmed no internet connection in a web browser
```

What am I missing?

#### UPDATE

I've confirmed that dynamically loading `wininet.dll` and using GetProcAddress to find the method "InternetGetConnectedState" gives exactly the same result with the internet disconnected (returns True and the parameter is set to "18").

Comment: It's close on pointless to test this. Just try to connect. If you don't get through, there's no connection.

Comment: Does that mean the Windows API function "InternetGetConnectedState" is effectively useless for practical use?

Comment: The docs say: *A return value of TRUE from InternetGetConnectedState indicates that at least one connection to the Internet is available. It does not guarantee that a connection to a specific host can be established.*

Comment: Note that the input value of `dwConnectionTypes` is meaningless. That parameter is for output only. The result you get is equal to `INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN or INTERNET_RAS_INSTALLED`.

Comment: Hmm, can't think what "connection to the internet" might have been available on my system! The function is effectively useless then and a test connection is the only sure method. Is it possible to attempt a general test connection, to some random server that is guaranteed to be available, possibly using winsock::BeginConnect in a separate thread? We'd like to be able to show the service engineer whether the customer's machine is ready for remote support (via the 3rd party tool, TeamViewer) or to send reports to 3rd party applications on the LAN, etc.

Comment: @RobKennedy: OK, thanks. After checking the enumeration in the MSDN documentation I was able to confirm that.

Comment: There is no such thing as a server "guaranteed to be available." Maybe you're on a LAN with no external connection. Maybe you're behind a firewall. Maybe the transoceanic cable was cut. Maybe the "guaranteed" server was just hit by a meteor. Check for a connection to whatever server *you* need to be available.

Comment: In addition to what Rob said about the output, it is basically just telling you that you are connected to a LAN, and dial-up networking is installed. But just because you are connected to a LAN does not guarantee that the LAN is connected to the Internet.  So you do need to actually connect to an external server on the Internet to check whether you are connected to the Internet or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know if you are connected to the Internet, there is no other way that contacting a host on the internet.

**Correct** technically then you only know if that host is online, but that's often good enough, since if your program requires internet access it's because you need to cantact a host on the internet.

One way of doing that is using a  `TIdHTTP` from Indy:

```
uses
  IdHTTP;
```

uses
  IdHTTP;

```
function HasInternet: Boolean;
begin
  with TIdHTTP.Create(nil) do
    try
      try
        HandleRedirects := True;
        Result := Get('http://www.Google.com/') <> '';
      except
        Result := false;
      end;
    finally
      free;
    end;
end;
```

And then use it :

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := BoolToStr(HasInternet, True);
end;
```

But it would be bettet to try to contact you host.

Comment: Using the code, why does TIdHTTP.Get and TIdHTTP.Trace return a non-empty string (and work) but all of the following throw an exception and fail (note I have added a space in "http://" to stop my strings being converted into URLs, they are correct in my code!):
http : //www.teamviewer.com/, http : //www.bbc.co.uk/, http : //microsoft.com/
In fact, I could not get anything *except* stackoverflow to work.

Comment: Because it redirects to https. See my updated answer.

Comment: Interesting. That improves things for some servers (now www.bbc.co.uk works) but not for others (www.microsoft.com continues to fail). The specific server I want to test a connection to is master14.teamviewer.com...and your updated code fixes that. Good...but any idea why www.microsoft.com continues to fail?

Comment: UPDATE: By checking the exception when trying to connect to www.microsoft.com, I find that the EIdHTTPProtocolException is raised. The message is: "Indy raised a protocol error!<CR>HTTP status code: 403<CR>Error messageHTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden". Any ideas? Can this exception still be classed as a "valid connection to the internet is possible"?

Comment: You can indeed since 403 is a error code you got from the server. Try to disable your internet connection and test the function. If you want the real HTML response as your browser gets you must ad SSL